# Seal script identification/translation

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, transcription

Please flag or comment if this type of request is not allowed — from searching on this SE community it seems like these types of questions are fairly common. I've tried some of the links in accepted and upvoted answers on related questions, but it turns out that figuring out radicals from seal scripts, or trying to decipher grass script (if that's what this is?), when you don't know how to read Chinese characters at all, is actually not so simple!

I picked up this scroll painting recently and am unable to identify it with reverse image search/Google Lens/etc. The first character in the upper seal looks similar to one in a related question, but the rest is very different. I've included photos of the poem and actual painting as well, in case someone recognizes them.

[image: Seals]
[image: Poem/inscription]
[image: Painting]

Comment: “identify it with reverse image search/Google Lens/etc.” it’s impossible lah, at this moment  maybe with a i, we could do it in decades, **maybe** 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I was thinking if the painting was a copy, or something mass-produced, reverse image search would find that — I didn't think I would have any luck with the seals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 寅嘯]

> 寅嘯
>
> *Yínxiào*, an [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name)

[image: 虎山画廊]

> 虎山画（畫）廊
>
> *Hǔshān halls of art*

Calligraphy:

> 閑（閒）來無事悠悠、［年〻］（年年）有餘［樂乐］（樂樂）
>
> *Always unhurried and at leisure, with joyous abundance as the years go by* (non-literal translation)
>
> 丙子年夏日寅嘯？于上海乕（虎）山畫苑
>
> I can't read 「？」, but this most likely says *Drawn by Yínxiào in the summer of [bǐngzǐ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%99%E5%AD%90) at Shànghǎi's Hǔshān painting gardens*.

Comment: it’s the simplified version of the character “繪” in cursive script 

Comment: Yes, that seems likely!

Comment: frankly, i’m severely prejudiced, that, calligraphy must be in traditional chinese; and mixing traditional & simplified together in art works is, . . . unbearable 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I don't think there's Simplified Chinese in here. I used some Simplified characters in the transcription to help the OP recognise characters. Everything that looks like Simplified Chinese here should be just 草書 of orthodox characters.

Comment: “樂乐” lah ^o^, the author could use the repeat symbol, like the one used in “年年” 

Comment: I think 樂 in 草書 is supposed to look very similar to 乐, but yes, maybe it could have been written as 樂〻. But actually, I don't remember the last time I saw 〻 at the end of a phrase, is that even allowed?

Comment: i’m not sure 

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning a lot from the comments here :)